# Trying to configure APM Agent for APM in ELK Stack 7.3.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm, kibana-7

Using ELK Stack 7.3.2 running on Linux.

APM Server is running.

APM Agent is running.

I am able to see the name of the process I am monitoring but I am not getting data.

I am not getting any transaction, errors or metrics.

Comment: Please add the logs of both the agent and the APM server. Otherwise this is just guessing (like maybe a firewall issue).